# How to bind and display a set of colors in WPF listview?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, binding

Im struggling with a problem that might seem easy first: I want to display some grid with different colors. I have a listview that is binded to a list. The list containst Colors (i have tried SolidColorBrush as well). The listview can display the elements, so in the current case you can see 1 grid per item. I want to bind the background of the grid (so the datatemplate) to the color property itself. For example: lets say i have a white and black color in my list. Then i want to display a black and a white grid using listview.
However, i cannot bind the background to anything, the binding always fails and I couldnt find a solution.

Here is the xaml code:

```
 <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding lightColors}" Height="30"  HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding **WHAT TO WRITE HERE?**}"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">

                                <Grid  Height="30" Width="30"></Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel>

                    </WrapPanel>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>

            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

And some code snippets:

```
 public List<Color> lightColors { get; set; }

  public void fillLightColors()
    {
        Color myColor = Color.FromRgb(100, 150, 75);
        LightColor.Add(myColor);
      
    }
```

Currently i cant see anything whenever i try to bind to the background.
Maybe im missing something obvious, maybe i have to use something totally else. Any help would be appriciated!

Comment: As long as you do not set the ListView's `View` property, you should use the simpler base class ListBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use a SolidColorBrush as value of the Setter:

```
<Setter Property="Background"> 
    <Setter.Value> 
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding}"/>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Besides that, the ControlTemplate must also use the Background property:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Grid Height="30" Width="30"
          Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Also note that when you set the ListViewItem's Template like this, the `ItemTemplate` is not used at all. The ControlTemplate should have a `ContentPresenter`.

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Grid Height="30" Width="30"
          Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
        <ContentPresenter/>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Hi! Sorry for answering late, this solution works! I dont know how to mark this as a solution, but thank you!

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

Style:

```
<Style x:Key="ColorComboStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=(global:GlobalVars.AllBrushes)}"/>
    <Setter Property="SelectedValuePath" Value="Name"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="24">
                    <DockPanel  LastChildFill="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <Rectangle DockPanel.Dock="Right" Fill="{Binding}" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Height="20" Width="20"/>
                        <Label Padding="2" Content="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                    </DockPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The GlobarVars property looks like this:

```
public static List<string> AllBrushes { get; } = typeof(Brushes).GetProperties().Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

Then use a ComboBox like this:

```
<ComboBox Style="{StaticResource ColorComboStyle}" SelectedValue="{Binding ...}"/>
```

Worked very well in my case... You will just need to adapt the code to work in your ListView.